# C# devexpress lookupedit Colums get the value

Tags: devexpress

Lookupedit  editvaluechange event     BirimFiyat Colums get the value ?

Lookeditup  load

```
  AnlasmaKalemleri.Properties.DataSource = WinTools.TabloParametre("SP_ANLASMA_COMBO", "@PROJEID",
                "@FİRMAID",
                PROJEIDLookUpEdit.EditValue.ToString(), FİRMAIDLookUpEdit.EditValue.ToString());

            AnlasmaKalemleri.Properties.DisplayMember = "TANIM";
            AnlasmaKalemleri.Properties.ValueMember = "ID";
```

Birimfiyat get the value ?

[image]

Comment: ...what are you trying to say...?

Comment: lookupedit get the monetary value of the selected box

Comment: Yes   Solved : )    BİRİMFİYATTextEdit.Text = AnlasmaKalemleri.Properties.GetDataSourceValue("BİRİMFİYAT", 0).ToString();